# Edit IPO curve does not work

Tags: animation, blender-internal-render-engine, nla-editor, graph-editor

I want to edit the IPO curve on blender. In the Graph editor,I select Ylocation curve then I hit T and I choose linear but the curve does not change to linear (image 1 vs image 2). I have tried other interpolation mode, but the result is the same.

[image: image1]
[image: image2]

Answer (score 3):

You have to select the **keyframes** you want to affect first and then change the interpolation type.

[image]